No 'Import a pipeline' button in Azure DevOps
I'm migrating my pipelines from AppCenter to Azure DevOps following the official documentation. However, when I try to import my JSON to Azure DevOps, there is no 'Import a pipeline' button.
Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/export-to-azure-pipelines#create-azure-pipeline
My Azure DevOps screen:

I saw a YouTube video, and there is an Import button too. Is there something I forgot to activate or something?

I'd guess that it's outdated. Classic  (JSON) pipelines are deprecated in favor of YAML

I will try YAML tomorrow. Thanks!

Please go to project setttings-> Pipelines -> Settings -> Make sure you toggled off Disable creation of classic build pipelines.

Then you can import json for Build pipeline:


It solved my problem! Thanks. For those who are reading this, follow the new YAML pipelines guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/appcenter/build/export-to-azure-pipelines#export-using-the-yaml-file
